# HTML | Can I assign type=button and type=submit in one button?

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to assign `type=submit` and `type=button` in one button like

```
<button type="button" type="submit></button>
```

I need to use  the `type=submit` so that I can put all the answers in my database and `type=button` to bring them to another modal. That's why I'd like to use both types in one button. I hope you can help me or teach some alternatives. Thank you

```
<form class="mt-1" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
   <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName">
   </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#confirmModal" >Next</button>
</form>
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Your form has been submitted</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary "  data-bs-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't. Use Javascript

Comment: since you like to submit and open another modal at same action you can use JS to submit the form and then on response open modal

Comment: You may use, in Javascript, the `event` to prevent the default `submit` behaviour until required so the button can be used for progress through your UI until the point where the `submit` is required. By supplying both `type` attributes it is unclear which would take precedence

Comment: Basically you are trying to show modal message after form submit ?

Comment: @Shibon
yes that's right

Comment: If you try to submit and open a modal on the same action, you must use javascript. 
If you submit, the form is sent to the server and the page (re)load. Even if you manage to open the modal you lose it once the page change. If you want to open the modal before data is sent use javascript and send data on modal close, otherwise open the modal in the submit page with the data you receive via POST.

Answer (score 0):

You cant add more than one type on a button, usually when you try and do a submit its better to do a 'type="submit"' on the form itself, if the button is inside the form it usually recognizes it and tells the form to submit, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 2 different types. But you can just use `type="button"`.
Regular buttons dont fire forms only if they got `type="submit"` otherwise they just perform a click action that is not bound to anything.
So since you have a `<button type="button" ...>Confirm</button>` there are different ways to achive your goal.

1. Propably the simplest way, add a onClick submit event

   ```
   <button type="button" 
           class="btn btn-primary"  
           data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
           onClick="submit()"        <====
   >Confirm</button>
   ```
2. You can do the same thing and more stuff if you add a js file, get the button and bind a onClick event or listen to the click event
   (no demo here, if you not know what im talking about, read some about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/)
3. You can give the button a `type="submit"` and change the way how modal seeks for the button. I recommend `ID` or `CLASS` instead of `TYPE`